# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, string

This program I'm making  isn't compiling right, I keep getting the error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -9
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:687)
 at pro1.main(pro1.java:161)

Here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class pro1 {
    static String str="";
    static String str1="";
    static int range=250;
    static int length;
    static String key="";
    static String ep="";
       static String pt="";
    static char temp;
    static int t,p,h;
    static int r,x,y,z,w;
    static Random generator = new Random();
 static public String getContents(File aFile) 
   {
   StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
   try {
      BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile));
      try {
        String line = null; 
        while (( line = input.readLine()) != null){
          contents.append(line);
          contents.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
      }
      finally {
        input.close();
      }
    }
    catch (IOException ex){
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    str1=contents.toString();
    return str1;
    }



public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
      File testFile = new File("/home/amritha/Desktop/sam.txt");
      System.out.println("Original file contents: " + getContents(testFile));
      System.out.println("message:"+str1);
       String sbox="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
       length=str1.length()-1;
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
        {
           t=(int)str1.charAt(i);
             if(t==32)
              {
               int t1=32;
               temp=(char)t;
              }
            else
              {
               range=generator.nextInt(26)+1;
               temp=sbox.charAt(range);
              }
              key+=""+temp;
        }
       System.out.println("Key:"+key);
       for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
       {
         t=(int)str1.charAt(i);
          {
            if(t==32)
             {
               t=32;
               temp=(char)t;
             }
            else
             {
               t-=97;
             }
          }
        p=(int)key.charAt(i);
          {
           if(p==32)
            {
               p=32;
               temp=(char)p;
            }
           else
            {
              p-=97;
            }
          }
        if((t==32)&&(p==32))
           {
                int v=32;
                temp=(char)v;
           }
           else
           {
            r=(t+p)%26;
           temp=sbox.charAt(r);
           }
           ep+=""+temp;
       }
         System.out.println("Encrypted Text:"+ep);

   for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
       {
         y=(int)ep.charAt(i);
          {
            if(y==32)
             {
               y=32;
               temp=(char)y;
             }
            else
             {
               y-=97;
             }
          }
        x=(int)key.charAt(i);
          {
           if(x==32)
            {
               x=32;
               temp=(char)x;
            }
           else
            {
              x-=97;
            }
          }
        if((x==32)&&(y==32))
           {
                int w=32;
                temp=(char)w;
           }
           else
           {
            z=(y-x)%26;
           temp=sbox.charAt(z);
           }
           pt+=""+temp;
       }
         System.out.println("deccrypted Text:"+pt);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't just put your entire program on here and expect someone to read through the whole thing and find your error (especially since you didn't even go through the trouble to mark the line that throws the exception or properly format your question). Also: If the program throws an exception, it clearly did compile just fine.

Comment: You have a mistake here: `length=str1.length()-1; for(int i=0;i<length;i++)`. Either use `i<=length` or `length=str1.length();` but otherwise you will miss the last character. (*Clearly, this is not the reason for the error*)

Comment: You have some crazy (ab)use of static variables. You might want to refactor that as well.

Comment: Btw. there is something called *debugger* with which you can go through your code step by step and check what values the variables have.

Comment: wlecome to stackoverflow sepp2k. I think posting code is more ok than asking something you can google.

Answer (score 4):

Your code looks fishy in every way, and I cannot imagine anyone wanting to read 170 lines of this code.

Look at the exception: It tells you exactly what's going wrong: You pass -9 to charAt() as an index, which is - obviously - out of range, as you should only pass 0 ... (length-1) in there.

And it gives you the line number, too... so go to line number 161 and look what's in there and how it got there.

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be it has something to do with this line:

```
z=(y-x)%26;
```

If x is larger than y the result of the % operation may be negative (or 0). And charAt (which is what z is given as parameter to) expects a positive value.
You should try:

```
z=Math.abs(y-x)%26;
```

Edit: As a side note, this shouldn't be to hard to figure out on your own, by looking at the exception as was pointed out by others, or in the worst case using a debugger and seeing exactly what values the different variables have and why when the exception occurs.

Comment: Another index out of bounds error waiting to happen is sbox, as it's only 26 characters long, yet it's being indexed randomly from 1 to 26.  Valid indices are from 0 to 25, remember.

Comment: Yes, indeed, thanks for the input, I missed that. I guess I was only paying attention for probable negative indices. To OP: `range=generator.nextInt(26)+1;` should be `range=generator.nextInt(26);`

Comment: It looks like he wanted the (y-x)%26 to be the reverse of (t+p)%26. Math.abs(..) wouldn't work that way.  I typically use something like this for negative wrap-around: `z -= x; while (z < 0) z += 26;`